# Class name in Facebook registration

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

What should be the class name which registering the Android App in facebook.
[image]

Comment: Well.. Maybe the name of your Activity which will use FB API

Comment: I am not sure weather it is a Launcher activity or the activity which calls the facebook API. Any concrete answer ?

Comment: I really don't know but [this (step 6)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#login), [this one](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/#prerequisities) and this quote: "You will also need to return to this dashboard and **add your app's package name and main activity class** once you have created a new Android project itself" might help you.

Comment: when you open fb login dialog it'll launch fb official app. once you complete login then fb app redirects to your app back. So you have to write activity name where you want to fb app redirect after login success. Hope you got me.

Comment: @iappmaker which class did you end up using in the lifecycle of your app ?

Comment: I finally used the class which uses the facebook. In mycase the scorecard will have the facebook icon, hence I used the scorecard class

Answer (score 4):

You have to **mention the name of the class (the Activity) which calls the Facebook API**. And as mentioned in the comments and I too have tried the same, you have to mention the Activity name which uses Facebook API and **not the Main Activity of your application**.